# How to make a queryset with "or" statement

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model Article, in Article i have title and article

I have a search function and whatever type in the search must get me all the articles that have the search text in title or article

```
def searh(request):
    print(request.POST)
    kw = request.POST['search']
    articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=kw).filter(article__contains=kw)
    context = {'News':articles}
    return render(request, 'menu/search_results.html', context )
```

by this query is not accurate doesn't return me the if in both

how to structure it?

```
  articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=kw).filter(article__contains=kw)
```

My search form

```
            <form method="POST" class="search-box" action="{% url 'search' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input  class="site-search" type="text" placeholder="{% trans 'Търси..' %}" name="search">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Where do you have your search field in your template ?

Comment: @Ducky in the navbar as a form :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, you have to use :

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    kw = request.POST.get('search')
    articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=kw) | Q(article__contains=kw))
    context = {'News':articles}
    return render(request, 'menu/search_results.html', context )
```

Comment: I've submitted my template but i don't know why do you need it :) ty for the answer will try it right away

Comment: You added your template after my answer. Anyway, you have a search field and you would like to display result that's it ?

Comment: Perfect, glad to helped you ;)